# If function has a zero on an open set, then it has a zero on the boundary

Tags: several-complex-variables

**Question**: Let $D\subset \mathbb{C}^N$ for $N\geq 2$ be open, bounded and connected and let $f: \overline{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be continuous such that $f$ is holomorphic on $D$. Show that if $f$ has a zero on $D$, then $f$ has a zero on $\partial D$.

I'm not 100% sure how start this. I was thinking of maybe trying to use the maximum modulus principle to arrive at a contradiction but I don't really get anywhere.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The maximum modulus prinicple approach is probably not going to be successful, since this result is false for $n = 1$. With some further assumptions on $D$, the result would apply from applying Hartogs' Theorem to $1/f$; would something like that work here?

Comment: Good point! I did originally try using the Hartog's extension phenomenon, namely that $1/f$ can be extended holomorphically to the whole of $D$. Then perhaps extending it continuously to $\overline{D}$ but again, I don't really get anywhere. Also, what extra assumptions on $D$ would I need? These are the only ones that have been given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question, had use that the the zero set for $N\geq 2$ has no isolated points, but that if $Z(f)$ doesn't intersect the boundary, it is clearly bounded. Hence it is compact and therefore finite, leading to a contradiction :)